# Why do fans keep running after power-off

Tags: fan

What is the reason why the fan of many electronic devices, such as video projectors, laser printers or kitchen ovens (have to) continue running after the device has been powered off?

It is my understanding that fans are required to bring fresh air for cooling to the device. Without it, the device might overheat. But once the device is powered off, there is no more source for the heat, and therefore no more risk to overheat.

Comment: could be the huge-ass power supply caps and simple control circuitry use the fans to not only discharge the caps afterwards (thus rendering the device at a safer, discharged lower voltage) and also as Olin says, provide a little more after-action cooling! Depends on the device of course.

Comment: Components have thermal inertia (imagine a hot skillet after you turn the gas off).  They can remain warm after the power has been turned off.   Keeping components cool prolongs their life.

Comment: Definitely for projectors and cooking appliances. Turn off the power and the - already hot - components remain hot, and that heat could damage other things or make the case dangerously hot (melt plastic). So the fan runs until the hot parts reach a safe temperature

Answer (score 14):

Some devices have hot spots such that the heat needs to continue to be removed for a while after it stops being produced.  There is a lag as the heat energy conducts to where the moving air can take it away.  If the air no long takes the heat away and the original source stays hot enough for a while, the parts in the airflow would get hotter than during normal operation.  This could be bad, especially for devices that are designed at the edge of the ability to remove the heat to avoid damage.

### Added about storage to run fan

Some are suggesting that devices that run the fan a while after soft off should have energy storage to guarantee this even if power is suddenly removed.  This doesn't make sense except in extreme critical applications, which does not apply to ordinary comsumer products like projectors.

I used a small fan in a product recently to provide forced air flow over a 150 W power supply.  It was a Qualtek FAD1-06025BBHW12.  The airflow (24 CFM) feels rather wimpy to me compared to what I've felt coming out of projectors, so we can consider keeping this fan powered for a minute to be a conservative estimate of the energy required.

This fan is rated for 1.75 W.  That times one minute is 105 J.  Let's see how big a capacitor would have to be to deliver that much energy.  Let's say it would be a 20 V cap, and we'd have a buck converter running the fan until the cap gets down to 5 V.  Let's say the buck converter would be 85% efficient, so the cap has to store 124 J.

The energy stored in a capacitor is:

E = ½ C V<sup>2</sup>

Working this equation to get a difference of 124 J from 20 V to 5 V shows that it would take 660 mF.  That's over half a Farad, which is huge.  Not only would that be expensive, but also quite large relative to the size of a ordinary consumer projector.  These kind of capacitors usually have 20% tolerance at least, and you don't want to run them at their full voltage to get reasonable lifetime.  So you'd need to spec around 825 mF and 25 V.  A quick check on Mouser shows that any such cap is going to cost around $100, even in production quantities.  That would probably add at least $300 to the end user and make the unit bigger.

Would you pay $300 more for a projector that is a bit more robust in the event of a power failure or you do something stupid like pull the plug out?  Keep in mind that a ordinary projector isn't guaranteed to be damaged this way.  It's not going to be good for it, and the lifetime of the bulb and possibly the projector will be reduced, but it's probably not going to break outright if this were done once or twice.  Most consumers aren't even going to know of this issue, and buy the projector that does the same thing but costs $300 less.  Even if they are aware of this issue and actually believe the claims by the manufacturer, most will probably figure they'll be careful and not pull the plug out until the fan stops, and take their chances with a sudden power failure.

So leaving out energy storage to run the fan isn't bad design at all.  Burdening the product with expensive features that few understand and even fewer care about, especially in a very cost competitive market, would be bad design.  Good design is looking at the *whole* product, not knee-jerking about a particular issue in isolation.

Comment: Wait, so if I've been using my projector for a while and the power suddenly goes out that could damage my projector? That doesn't seem like a very good design to me...

Comment: @Ajedi32 Indeed, if the power suddenly goes of your projector could get damaged. Also when you turn of a projector it is important not to immediately plug it off but to wait until the fans stopped. Most manufacturers even put warnings on the projector. I don't see any other way manufacturers could handle this, so I wouldn't call it bad design.

Comment: @wumm Yeah, I realize there's probably a trade-off here. I guess it just seems like bad UX if a relatively normal occurrence (e.g. the user unplugging the projector) could physically damage the equipment, even if you do warn the user about it. Oh well, I guess that's kind of beside the point for this question.

Comment: @Ajedi32: A larger and more expensive bulb operated at lower temperature would be less efficient and consequently generate more heat per unit of light output, and would thus require more cooling, but would be able to withstand unexpected loss of power to the fan.  Unless power failures are a frequent occurrence, overall product usability would probably be better with a smaller bulb.  That having been said,...

Comment: ...I wonder how expensive it would be to either have a battery or mechanical backup [flywheel or clockwork spring] to power the fan briefly on a shutdown?  I don't think the amount of power or energy required would be particularly large, especially since the fan wouldn't have to dissipate much radiated heat from the bulb, but merely conducted heat.

Comment: @supe: Projectors I've seen run the fan for a minute or more after the bulb is shut off. That's a significant amount of energy. I think the manufacturers rightly feel that the extra expense to run the fan that long after power is removed would make the product uncompetitively priced. You'd have to spend a lot on marketing to explain the situation and get people to understand why this matters, then most customers are going to think *"screw that, I'll take my chances"* and buy the cheaper unit anyway. I probably would. I just don't see it making commercial sense.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Letting the fan run longer than needed doesn't really have a downside for the manufacturer.  Even when things have stabilized to the point that they no longer need cooling, they will still be hot enough to be more fragile than when cold.  Users are less likely to pick up the projector while the fan is running, but may regard the turning off of the fan as a sign that it's safe to move.  Otherwise, while a cap or rechargeable battery large enough to run the fan might be expensive, disposable batteries would be relatively cheap given that they won't be used often.  Basically...

Comment: ...the purpose of the circuitry would be "insurance"; as such, it might increase the attractiveness of the unit to anyone who has had a bulb break due to power failure or knows someone who has.

Comment: @supercat Olin's point is that nobody will buy the projectors with this feature because they'll be more expensive.

Comment: @immibis: I've seen slide projector bulbs which would fail with high probability within a few seconds if bulb power and fan power were cut simultaneously; I wouldn't be surprised if running the fan for even one second at full speed and five seconds at half speed would reduce by 90% or more the probability of such failure.  There are advantages to having a fan run longer (e.g. a user might think that after the fan shuts off it's safe to open up the projector and swap out the bulb) but in "emergency" situations I think even a few seconds would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Projectors and other devices with a large incandescent lamp inside need to be continuously cooled.  While lit, the running fan keeps the glass envelope cool so it doesn't melt and balloon out.  When the lamp is turned off "stored" heat inside continues to heat the glass, so cooling for a period after the lamp is turned off is required.  Failure to do this can cause the lamp to burst.  (Of course, with more and more projectors using LEDs for illumination this is no longer the issue it was at one time.

Other devices similarly need be kept cool, to optimize component life.

Comment: Video projectors typically use gas discharge (metal-halide) lamps rather than incandescent lamps.

Answer (score 1):

For my **stove,** I found the explanation in its manual. As the air inside cools down, water vapour condensates. The moist would provide a substrate for bacteria. So the fan keeps running to bring out the moist.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use a video projector it "overheats". A video projector has a finite lifespan and every time you use it the usage damages it a bit. Cooling it down after using it then reduces that damage as the projector is for a shorter time frame at a high temperature.